# Code works in chrome and firefox but fails in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>



<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function abc()
{
ansArray = ['a'];   
document.write('<input type = "button" value = "a">');
document.write('<input type = "button" value = "b">');
var myButton = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

myButton[0].onclick = function() {
    if(ansArray[0] == 'a')
        myButton[0].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    else
        myButton[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

myButton[1].onclick = function() {
    if(ansArray[0] == 'b')
        myButton[1].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    else
        myButton[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="abc()">
</body>
</html>
```

This code segment is to change the colour of the two buttons on click event,works fine in chrome and firefox but the onclick functions does not work in IE9. Please help... Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the IE requires a semicolon after the onclick-function

Comment: Just step through with a debugger and see what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the function like

```
(function abc(){
    // code here
})();
```

Also use `;` after each function expression, i.e. `myButton[0].onclick = function() {...};`.

[Working here](http://jsfiddle.net/nsgkG/1/).

Comment: debugger does not show any error (console), I used a semicolon after each function as well. In actual case the function is big enough to write as(function abc(){
    // code here
})();

Comment: (function abc(){
    // code here
})(); - is working fine Thanks